Extract points from or convert usd file
I need to extract all vertices from a usd/a file, currently I'm doing it like this:
from pxr import Usd, UsdGeom, Sdf

def extract_points_from_usd(file_path):
    """Extracts 3D points from a USD or USDA file."""
    stage = Usd.Stage.Open(file_path)
    points = []

    for prim in stage.Traverse():
        if prim.IsA(UsdGeom.Mesh):
          usd_points = UsdGeom.Mesh(prim).GetPointsAttr().Get()
          if usd_points:
              points.extend(usd_points)

    return np.array(points)

But it's not accurate as there seems to be fewer vertices and all the Z values are either 0 or very close to 0.
I need this to make a point cloud file (.las), alternatively, I could transform the .usd file to .ply and convert that to a point cloud, which is much more straight forward, but I can't find the way to do that conversion on python script. This is for an aws lambda function so I can't rely on software like blender or cloudcompare.

pxr is from nvidia, right?

I think so, yeah
